# Formatting strings to time-based data type

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of strings that represent different timed race results of varying time intervals (ss:SS, mm:ss.SS, hh:mm:ss).

I would like to standardize the time intervals in a common format that supports all of these formats, and is able to be handled across languages.

I will want to do calculations on these times, store them in a database, as well as convert them back to the original string to be displayed

My current thoughts are the following

`myTimespans = [ "12.04", "1:00.42", "4:19:27" ]`

produces something like

```
myOutput = [ (0,0,12,04),(0,1,0,42),(4,19,27,0) ]

 # or in datetime

myOutput = [ 00:00:12.04, 00:01:00.42, 4:19:27.00 ]

 # or in milliseconds

 myOutput = [ 12040, 60042, 15582000 ]
```

Not sure which is the most practical to implement, and how I should write a python script to convert the strings.

Any tips / suggestions appreciated!

Comment: I have a tip:  Be specific in your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `datetime` or `dateutil` library to parse them into datetime format. I just use regular expression to clean string first.

```
import re
from dateutil import parser

d = ["12.04", "1:00.42", "4:19:27"]
d_sub = [re.sub('\.', ':', d_) for d_ in d]
print([parser.parse(d_) for d_ in d_sub]) # list in datetime format
```

As mentioned in the comment, question should be more specific.

Comment: No problem @Zach. Hope it helps a bit.

Answer (score 1):

[`import datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)!

Specifically,

[`datetime.datetime.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime)

[strftime() and strptime() Behavior](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)

Comment: Thanks Charlie! My previous question was a little unclear would you still recommend datetime.datetime.strptime()?

Comment: I'm still a little confused. You'd have to define different `strptime` formats conforming to each item's format in `myTimespans`, but yes, I'd still recommend it. Be sure to save the `strptime` formats you used so you can reuse them in `strftime`

Comment: It'd be a good way to standardize your calculations you have to do. (Also an upvote never hurt nobody :) )